# Slideshow on key press not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, slideshow, onkeypress

So I have this code. I'm doing something wrong. I want the left arrow to go back (show the previous image) but it isn't working. It shows the next image (like the right arrow). Whatever arrow I click, left or right it shows the next image. I've tried millions of different things and I can't seem to find the problem. Can anyone help me?

I also like the sources to loop. When the last source from the array has been reached, I want to loop back to the first source again (and to the last source when you reach the first).

Btw, I also have a code for the image to change on click. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the problem, but I decided to keep it, just in case it's messing something up.
Thank you :)

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="slideshow"> 
        <img alt="slideshow" src="1.jpg" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    var imgs = ["2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];

    function changeImage(dir) {
        var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
        img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
    }

    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
        } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            changeImage() // right -> show next image
        }
    }
</script>

<script language="javascript">
    var imgs = ["2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];
    function changeImage() {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = imgs[0];
        imgs.push(imgs.shift())
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you have redefined `changeImage` which does not handle going forwards or backwards .

Comment: How can I make it go back and forward then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you got a few things wrong:

- You have two variables with the same name.
- You have two functions with the same name.
- If a function expects an argument, you must always send an argument (or `null`), you can not only send `-1` for left, and nothing for right. (And in your case, you're actually making it more difficult for yourself by not sending a `1` for right).
- `|| imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0]`, doesn't do what you think it does. You're checking `dir` as if it's a boolean. JavaScript can interpret `1` and `-1` as booleans (`true` and `false` respectively), but because you only send along `-1` it will not work correctly.

Below is your code with these issues fixed:

---

**JS, HTML:**

```js
var imgs = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjC6V.jpg",
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eBBQ.gif",
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhjjB.png",
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNhjf.jpg",
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn175.png"];

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var e = event || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '37') { //LEFT
    changeImage(-1);
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') { //RIGHT
    changeImage(1);
  }
}

function changeImage(dir) {
  var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
  img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src)+dir] || imgs[(dir==1) ? 0 : imgs.length-1];
}
```

```css
#imgClickAndChange {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="slideshow"> 
    <img id="imgClickAndChange" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjC6V.jpg" alt="" onclick="changeImage(1)" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3wxhc58/8/**)

- In the ternary operator, instead of `(dir==1)` you could just use `dir`, since JavaScript translates a `1` to `true`. But using `(dir==1)` is safer because that will create a real boolean.
- I replaced the images in the `imgs`-array with links to images that actually exist, so that the script works without any errors.
- I added some CSS, this is only for the answer's sake, so that all images have the same size.

---

**If you don't want the images to loop, change the `changeImage()` function to this:**

```
function changeImage(dir) {
    var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    var newSrc = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src)+dir];

    if (imgs.indexOf(newSrc) != -1) { //only sets new src if it's in the imgs-array (i.e. if it exists)
        img.src = newSrc;
    }
}
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3wxhc58/9/**)

Comment: Thank you :) however I've tried this and it still doesn't work. It still changes the images forward even when I click the left arrow. And when I take this part of the code off:

   
            var imgs = ["2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];
                function changeImage() {
                    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = imgs[0];
                    imgs.push(imgs.shift())
                }
}
              

what happens is it goes back and forward correctly but only one time. It only shows 2 different images. any idea?

Comment: @Owly - I revised my answer, so that it really works with `img.src` instead of `img.alt`. If you still can't get this to work on your computer, you must be doing something else wrong, because both the *code snippet* and *jsfiddle* run perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: thank you. it's working perfectly fine with your images. Somehow with mine it doesn't work. The images are loading. But the javascript doesn't work. It only changes 2 images. I really must be doing something else wrong. I don't get it... :S

Comment: Can you post a link to your website? Then I can have a look at what exactly is happening there

Comment: The website is not online yet but I managed to make it work using imageshack. For some reason, when I use images from the internet it works. The same doesn't happen when the images are from my local folder.

Comment: But where are you testing the local images then? If you use a local path like `"1.jpg"`, the code searches for those images on your server, in the folder of your webpage. Couldn't that be the problem, that you are trying to load local images where that isn't possible?

Comment: The offer stands, if you can post a link to you testsite, whereever that is, I can have a look for you to see what the problem is. If you don't want that, that's alright too of course.