# Change three images with javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, image

I have 3 images and I want to change those images by clicking arrow image but I have a problem with that. 
I created some tracers to hold the pictures adresses but it doesn't work. 
When I use this function, it just changes the picture from first to third picture. So I can't show that 3 pictures in a row.
What I need is that when I click the arrow image to change the pictures in a row like first picture, second picture and third picture.

```js
function change(){
  img_tracer = new Array () ;
  img_tracer[0] = '1';
  img_tracer[1] = '2';
  img_tracer[2] = '3';

  images = new Array ();
  images[0] = document.getElementById('tech').src = "images1.jpg";
  images[1] = document.getElementById('tech').src = "images2.jpg";
  images[2] = document.getElementById('tech').src = "images3.jpg";

  if ( images[0] )
    img_tracer[0];
  else if ( images[1] )
    img_tracer[1];
  else if ( images[2] )
    img_tracer[2];

  var arrow1 = document.getElementById('arr1');

  if ( arrow1 ) {

    if (img_tracer[0])
      images[1];  
    else if (img_tracer[1])
      images[2];
    else if (img_tracer[2])
      images[2];
  }
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr><td width="100px;" id="arr1" name="arr1" background="imagesright.jpg"onclick="change()"></td><td>
    <img src="images1.jpg" alt="Technology" id="tech" name="tech" align="middle" /></td>
    <td width="100px;" id="arr2" name="arr2" background="imagesleft.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat" onclick="change()">
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

I'd appreciate if you'd help me.

Comment: You are making this harder than it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/xms7v9vv/

**HTML:**

```
<table align="center">
  <tr><td width="100px;" id="arr1" name="arr1" background="imagesright.jpg"onclick="change(this)"></td><td>
    <img src="images1.jpg" alt="Technology" id="tech" name="tech" align="middle" /></td>
    <td width="100px;" id="arr2" name="arr2" background="imagesleft.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat" onclick="change(this)">
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var images = [];
images[0] = "images1.jpg";
images[1] = "images2.jpg";
images[2] = "images3.jpg";

var currentImage = 0;

var change = function(td){
  if(td.getAttribute("name") == "arr1"){
    // Go left
    --currentImage;
    if(currentImage == -1)
      currentImage = 2;
  }else{
    // Go right
    ++currentImage;
    if(currentImage == 3){
      currentImage = 0;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('tech').src = images[currentImage];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be effective enough. You should only have 1 array with all the images and just update the current index.

```js
var currentId = 0;

function setImage(id, src) {
  document.getElementById(id).src = src;
}

var images = [
  "http://placehold.it/200x160/ff0000/00ffff.png&text=1",
  "http://placehold.it/200x160/00ff00/ff00ff.png&text=2",
  "http://placehold.it/200x160/0000ff/ffff00.png&text=3"
];

window.change = function(direction) {
  currentId += direction;

  if (currentId > images.length - 1) {
    currentId = 0;
  } else if (currentId < 0) {
    currentId = images.length-1;
  }

  setImage('tech', images[currentId]);
}
```

```css
.nav {
  border: thin solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="nav" width="100px;" id="arr1" name="arr1" onclick="change(-1)">&lt;</td>
    <td align="center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x160/ff0000/00ffff.png&text=1" alt="Technology" id="tech" name="tech" />
    </td>
    <td class="nav" width="100px;" id="arr2" name="arr2" onclick="change(1)">&gt;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a variable for the current index, [**try this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26578247/3407923)

Comment: @myfunkyside: Thanks, but I guess that I wanted to make this as simple to understand.

Comment: @BurakULU: If this answer answers your question, please provide feedback. Thanks.